# Hyperlink in google sheets that opens up a specific outlook email template

Tags: email, hyperlink, outlook, google-sheets, outlook-2013

I would like some assistance with this matter as I've only been able to get a regular email to open directly from sheets when inserting an E-Mail Hyperlink.

The current code that I have is =hyperlink("mailto:@gmail.com&Subject=TEst&Body=TEst%0Aand%0ATest%202", "Email").

I need a way for the link to open specific outlook email templates that are located on my desktop.

Thank you for any light you can shed on the subject.

Best,
-Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the job done.

If you use an Internet Explorer you may consider automating Outlook from a script. But this solution will not work in other browsers. See [Compose and Send E-mail from JavaScript by using Outlook Automation 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rajnishkaushik/archive/2007/05/06/compose-and-send-e-mail-from-javascript-by-using-outlook-automation-2007.aspx) for more information.

The only possible solution for all browsers is to use the [mailto: protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for opening a pre-filled new mail item.

Comment: Thank you, I will just have to try another approach.